# Unexplained field value change

Tags: java, debugging, reflection, variable-assignment

Take a look at this strange issue:

[image: Debugging steps]

1. I have a breakpoint on all access to the field `res1`
2. Res1 is assigned the value of f, which is "bar"
3. Res1 now is "bar"
4. At the next break, res1 is suddenly `null`

Why is this impossible?

- Because of the breakpoint on res1, I can see that it shouldn't have changed at all
- And it couldn't, because I don't explicitly change it between the assignment and the `assertEquals` and this code is running in a single JUnit thread.
- There are no other fields or variables named `res1`.

What could be up? I'm assuming it's not a bug in the JVM, but who knows.

---

As Jon Skeet said, the problem is that the instances are different. This is caused by this strange reflection issue:

```
public class ServiceObject {

    private static final Map<Class<?>, Map<String, Operation>> opsByClass =
        new ConcurrentHashMap<Class<?>, Map<String,Operation>>();

    private final Object target;
    private final Map<String, Operation> myClassOps;

    private class Operation {
        private final Method method;
        public Operation(Method met) {
            this.method = met;
            method.setAccessible(true);
        }
        public void execute(Map<String,?> args, Responder responder, Object context, boolean coerce) {
            ...
            method.invoke(target, mArgs);
        }
    }

    public ServiceObject(Object target) {
        Class<?> myClass = target.getClass();
        Map<String, Operation> op = opsByClass.get(myClass);
        if (op == null) {
            op = new HashMap<String, Operation>();
            for (Method meth : myClass.getMethods()) {
                ...
                op.put(opName, new Operation(meth));
            }
            opsByClass.put(myClass, op);
        }
        this.target = target;
        this.myClassOps = op;
    }

    public void execute(String opName) {
        Operation op = myClassOps.get(opName);
        ...
        op.execute(args, responder, context, coerce);
    }
}

// Foo is equivalent to the class that contains <res1> above
class Foo {

    @ServiceOperation
    public void bar() {
        // breakpoint here
    }

}
```

What happens when the tests are run:

```
a = new Foo();
b = new Foo();
svc = new ServiceObject(a);
svc.execute("bar", ...); // inside Foo.bar() <this> will be <a>
svc = new ServiceObject(b);
svc.execute("bar", ...); // inside Foo.bar() <this> will still be <a>, but should be <b>
```

Comment: Could you post some code as well?

Comment: Can you reduce it to the minimum amount of code needed to demonstrate the problem, and post the code in full?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess: you're looking at a different instance of the class during the assertion phase than you were when it was set to "bar".

It's hard to tell without seeing the rest of the code though.

EDIT: The problem is that your `opsByClass` cache is going to include an Operation, which implicitly has an associated `ServiceObject`. So when you create the first `ServiceObject` with a `Foo`, it will cache Operation instances associated with that first instance of `ServiceObject`. When you call `svc.execute` on the *second* instance of `ServiceObject`, it will look up the operation in the map, and find the `Operation` associated with the first instance... which probably isn't what you intended.

Comment: How could I not have checked that? Indeed it's the problem. Now off to find out why that's the case...

Comment: @Bart: I've edited my answer to explain what's going on, as far as I can.

Comment: Yeah, I realised the cause when editing my question to add some debugging steps I'd done. I've made `Operation` static now, with the target as a parameter in `execute`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've got your code spanning different tests. 
Suggest you do the setup in the onSetUp() method

Answer (score 0):

I found it. The problem is that because `Operation` is not `static`, it refers to the `ServiceObject` it was initially created by, not the one which the second call is executed upon.